# Why my android app in Play Store not offers to update?

Tags: android

I developed an Android app and installed it in a smartphone manually with the apk, in version 12. Then, I upload version 15 to Play Store.

In the smartphone I can search the app in the Play Store, but it not offers me to update the app. Only offers to "uninstall" or "open" the app.

Of course, I change the version in the AndroidManifest.

What is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also possible that you already installed latest version of the app while developing/testing.

SOLUTION: the app not offers me to update because I installed the older version manually. I remove the app in Play Store and then install it and then it offers me to update.

Comment: In the smartphone I have the version 12, I check it. I installed it manually with the apk (in release mode). In the play store there is the version 14.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it's possible that app isnt updating because you installed older version manually. You can try to uninstall it, then install from Play store and submit another update.

Comment: I think the same, but I want to be sure because of the registration process of the app is too long :)

Answer (score 0):

Play Store updates take time to propagate, so could just need to wait. Also could be you have a cached version of your app entry in play store app, so go to settings, apps, play store and clear cache and try again. Also make sure its the versionCode you changed in your manifest and gradle files, not version name.

Comment: I cleaned the cache and no changes. I am sure that I change versionCode and not another parameter.

Comment: If you locally delete your app and download from store, which version is shown? (15)?

Comment: I think yes, but I don't want to delete the app because of the registratino process... but if there is no changes I have to try this...

Comment: My advice is just to wait, my guess it will propagate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you set country distribution correctly.
2. Check if it has some restriction with your current device (like Android api, screen desnsity, device spec, et all). You can check it on AndroidManifest.xml, search for permission or hardware specs

As @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder said, PlayStore has a delay to delivery your new version of app

best regards